# ¿Cómo activar un entorno creado con conda en PowerShell?

Tags: python, conda

En `PowerShell` no me están funcionando los entornos (environments) creados con `conda`. Al momento de intentar activar, por ejemplo un entorno que se llama `py34`, utilizo `activate py34`.

Sin embargo, al momento de abrir el intérprete, me sigue mostrando el intérprete que está por defecto en la instalación, no el del entorno. ¿Existe alguna forma para activarlos?

Comment: ¿En cuál versión de Windows?

Comment: Lo he intentado en win10 y win7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

conda no soporta PowerShell aún, ver [esta incidencia](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/626). Por tanto, a día de hoy conda y Anaconda solo funcionan en `cmd.exe`.

Comment: ¿Quien ha votado negativo podría explicar su voto? http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: Si tocaría esperar por el momento, aunque por ahí me parecio que hay un script que funciona https://github.com/Liquidmantis/PSCondaEnvs pero por ahora no vale la pena complicarse demasiado.